# sensor to find if defined free space has an object obstacle

Tags: arduino

I am newbie to embedded programming, so please do assist me as much as possible.

I would like to know how can we built a device which will take care of the following situation

1. An area with a definite distance, width and height defined will be free of any obstacle.
2. An sensor scanning the above defined area for any obstacle.
3. If there is any obstacle for a stipulated period of time an action like beep sound or camera record should be triggered

I am planning to do this project using Arduino.

My question is how to solve the problem of #1 and #2? What all modules should I need to get this project started? How to go about with programming and configuration in terms of both hardware and software.

Comment: This is a programming site. Hardware questions are off-topic and your whole question is too broad.

Comment: @gre_gor where should I be asking this question? I thought as the point will involve discussion in regards to development also hence posted this question.

Comment: This is Questions and Answers site not a forum. If you want a discussion, this is not the site for it.

Comment: So what could be the best way to tweak my query to qualify as "Question and Answer", so I can get my questions answered?

Answer (score 0):

for first condition u need to measure length.... so u can do that by using 2 methods( as much as i kwn)

1.using ultrasonic sensor it will give u direct length upto its range(3m i think)

2.u can also use ir sensor this method is bit trick but i thik more accurate and interesting than first although it have some limitations or we can say that condition( the room has to be empty or there should be no obstacle in ur bot's path while ur measuring).Second how its gonna work first make a mark on wheel by using white strip or black marker(as u may kwn that ir sensor can detect difference between white and black colors easily thats y we often use it in line follower bots).once u make a mark then just simply put an ir sensor right front of ur wheel. And it will count number of rotations and then u can easily convert number of rotation to length by using 2TTRN formula where( R is the radius of wheel, TT is pie, N is the number of rotation of wheel